# How to log compile errors from torch.compile

Tags: numpy, pytorch

I'm new to torch and I try to speedup some mathematical computations using `torch.compile`.
I'm using pytorch: **pytorch 2.2.0 py3.11_cpu_0** from Anaconda.
The end goal is to parallelize my code on a GPU or TPU, but for starters I compile it to a C-Kernel.

Given the following self contained example in python:

```
import numpy as np
import torch


def test(foo, bar):
    return np.count_nonzero(foo) + np.count_nonzero(bar)

def test2(foo, bar):
    for clause in foo:
        for i in range(0, bar.shape[1]):
            res = np.logical_xor(clause, bar[i])
            if np.count_nonzero(res) == 1:
                bar[i] |= res
    return bar


foo = np.random.choice([True]*5 + [False]*5, size=(10,10))
bar = np.random.choice([True] + [False]*10, size=(10,10))

torch._logging.set_logs(output_code=True)

compiled = torch.compile(test)
compiled(foo, bar)
```

This code works and produces a logfile with translated python code and a C Kernel.
But if I replace the compile call to
`compiled = torch.compile(test2)`
to call my other function, it does not log anything.

How can I check the compiled code or even assure that compile did something?

Furthermore, the compilation seems to be triggered lazily and only when I execute the compiled function. How can I force to compile it earlier?

Answer (score 1):

As per [its documentation](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/torch_compile_tutorial.html), `torch.compile()` uses JIT (just in time) compilation based on the provided data the function should run on. This is then cached and reused if another call of the "compiled" function is compatible with the already compiled one. So there is no real way to force compilation without explicitly calling the "compiled" function with similar data as the compilation depends on the shape/type of the data.

Regarding your second function. `test2` does not return anything but only changes the referenced numpy-array. Afaik, this is not the intended use for `torch.compile()`. Data may be copied to the CUDA, which would not change a referenced numpy-array that is copied. I assume this leads to the `compile()` function not really compiling `test2`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I corrected to code to return the array, but still no output in the logs for the test2 function. torch.compile just silently fails. Even if this is not the intended use of the function, a proper warning or error should be expressed I think. Also I must have missed this "intention" in the description of the method.